# Caching in C# without System.Web

Tags: c#, caching

I want to be able to cache a few objects without referencing System.Web. I want sliding expiration and little more... Is there really no where to go but to build my own using a Dictionary and some selfmade expiration of objects - or are there something in the .NET framework I've totally missed out on?

Comment: You meant, "Caching in .NET without System.Web", and "I code in C#", right? You didn't really think that the C# programming language has a caching feature, did you?

Comment: **WHY** can't you use System.Web ?? Except for the psychological barrier, there's really nothing stopping you from using this assembly in a WinForms or console app - and why reinvent the wheel if there's already a solution out there???

Comment: @John: Actually yes, I did... Am I being naïve?  :o)

@marc_s: Don't give razorblades to babies - including System.Web might lead other fellow developers to believe in good faith that everything in it could (and should) be used in a non-UI layer. To me it feels extremely akward having something named "Web" in i.e. a business layer - call it a psychological barrier but that's also it  ;o)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try the [Microsoft Enterprise Library Caching Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203226.aspx).

Example utility function for caching on demand with a sliding timeout:

```
static T GetCached<T>(string key, TimeSpan timeout, Func<T> getDirect) {
    var cache = CacheFactory.GetCacheManager();
    object valueCached = cache[key];
    if(valueCached != null) {
        return (T) valueCached;
    } else {
        T valueDirect = getDirect();
        cache.Add(key, valueDirect, CacheItemPriority.Normal, null, new SlidingTime(timeout));
        return valueDirect;
    }
}
```

You can specify multiple expiration policies, including `SlidingTime`, `FileDependency`, `ExtendedFormatTime`, or you can write your own.

Comment: "In my opinion that block has way too many moving parts. Using the ASP.NET Cache is fairly lightweight, and includes the very useful cache dependancies stuff."- Scott Hanselman

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/UsingTheASPNETCacheOutsideOfASPNET.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at: [Domain Objects Caching Pattern for .NET](http://www.alachisoft.com/articles/domain_objects_caching_pattern.html)