# C# release lock automatically after timeout

Tags: c#, locking

does anyone have any ideas on whats the best way to implement a lock so that after X number of seconds it will automatically be released ?

Comment: That sounds like a bad idea.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I do agree with SLaks - its "unusual" to wait for X seconds for a lock.

Comment: Ideally I need to put together a generic class which will either raise and exception or automatically clear a lock after a timeout, i.e. somethings gone wrong with the method using the locking class

Comment: Having thought about this, I think you should consider an alternative design to your single lock. It would be better to think about what the "types of something" that can "go wrong" are, and to try to code a solution that breaks the problem down into several phases with possible recovery between each phase. The "lock" is there to protect data from being accessed by multiple threads simultaneously - don't remove that thread safety with this proposed time-lock mechanism - find some other way. You shouldn't leave that "gone wrong" thread active inside the "lock" code - find some way to abort it?

Comment: As a use case, I need to be able to lock on an Id but no longer than 5 seconds, after which others can obtain the lock. Due to the nature of our persistence (with expected versions), there are no issues with race conditions if two different threads both enter the locked region, I just want to make sure a hanging thread doesn't block others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In web development, I cache all the time with a sliding timeout. Perhaps you could use a cached object as the lock?

Here's a discussion of caching technologies in non-web applications:

[Caching in C# without System.Web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491933/caching-in-c-without-system-web)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are looking for an event to fire in X seconds, then I don't think there's any core Mutex object which currently provides the type of functionality you are looking for.

You could create this type of functionality by using a System.Timer (to fire in X seconds and release a locked Mutex) or by using a thread which Sleep's for X seconds - I'd prefer the first method.

However, both of these will be scheduled within the user/application layer - so you would have to wait for them to be scheduled.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `Monitor.TryEnter`. Please refer below -

[Synchronization problems with Monitor class in WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979422/synchronization-problems-with-monitor-class-in-wcf-service)

```
if(Monitor.TryEnter(lockObj, timeout)) {
    try {
        ...
    } finally {
        Monitor.Exit(lockObj);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure you fully understand me - Monitor.TryEnter (as far as I'm aware) will accept an Timespan after which it will stop trying to obtain the lock. In my case I have the lock and want it to automatically free itself after a timeout

Comment: @Johnv2020 If you have the lock, wait for some time and release it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use TransactionScope with TransactionOptions timeout parameter.

```
using (TransactionScope tx = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew,
                    new TransactionOptions() { Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10) }))
```

After the time ends, you will receive an TransactionAbortedException and the lock should be released.

It will be someting like this:

```
lock(_lock)
{
    try
    {
        using (TransactionScope tx = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew,
                        new TransactionOptions() { Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10) }))
        {
            //do somenting important stuff
            tx.Complete();
            tx.Dispose();  // just remembering that will be disposed.
        }
    }
    catch (TransactionAbortedException tex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Operation Timeout");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw; // do whatever you want
    }
}
```