# How to set a timeout for a lock (that has been acquired)?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, deadlock

I am recently working on a multithreaded project, and come across with a problem.
`SafeCreateProcessThread();` is being called every 220ms as long as the sensor is streaming.

```
public void StreamingDisplayMonitor()
    {
        var dtStartTemp = DateTime.Now;
        while (IsStreaming)
        {
            if ((DateTime.Now - dtStartTemp).TotalMilliseconds >= 220)
            {
                SafeCreateProcessThread();
                dtStartTemp = DateTime.Now;
            }
            if (SystemManager.bleTask.DicConnection.Count == 0) IsStreaming = false;
        }
    }
```

Here is the method that starts the thread:

```
private void SafeCreateProcessThread()
    {
        var th = new Thread(() => ProcessStreamingData());
        th.IsBackground = true;
        th.Start();
        th.Join(230);
        if (th.IsAlive)
        {
            // timeout
            // terminate the thread and release the lock
        }
    }
```

and the `ProcessStreamingData()` is as follows

```
private void ProcessStreamingData()
    {
        var sensorCount = ConnectedSensors.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < sensorCount; i++)
        {
            lock (lockObject1)
            {
                var sensor = ConnectedSensors[i];
                if (sensor.lst_streaming_data.Count > 0)
                {
                    var streamingPacket = sensor.lst_streaming_data.Last();
                    var calibrateMag = sensor.attitudeHelper.CalibrateStreamingPacket(streamingPacket, sensor);
                    sensor.attitudeHelper.MagDisturbDetect(sensor, streamingPacket, calibrateMag);
                    sensor.attitudeHelper.CalculateQuaternion(sensor, streamingPacket, calibrateMag);
                }
            }
        }
        this.Invoke(new Action(UpdateAllConnectedChart));
    }
```

as it goes, one of the threads became stuck at `sensor.attitudeHelper.MagDisturbDetect(sensor, streamingPacket, calibrateMag);` with some unknown reasons (without throwing any exceptions), it is a method within a 3rd party library. and as this problematical thread locks the `lockObject1`, all the new threads created can not run the code within the lock...

So in this case, using the cancellation token, stop flag seems not a right way to terminate the thread. I have tried the `.abort()` method, which, of course, makes the termination process unpredictable, therefore, it is not a good way either. and also `Monitor.TryEnter` can not do the job as it timeout the threads trying to acquire the lock, not the problematical one who owns the lock.

What I want to do is to terminate the problematical thread and release the lock when it is timeout. If there is anyone can tell me how to implement a reliable way to terminate a thread (the code block in `SafeCreateProcessThread()`).

```
if (th.IsAlive)
{
   // timeout
   // terminate the thread and release the lock
}
```

Thanks in advance.

the code in which the thread became stuck:

marked with // ------>

```
    public bool MagDisturbDetect(DSensor sensor, StreamingPacket streamingPacket, double[] calibratedMag)
    {
        if (lstMagXBuffer == null)
        {
            lstMagXBuffer = new List<double>();
            lstMagYBuffer = new List<double>();
            lstMagZBuffer = new List<double>();
        }

        if (lstRawMagXBuffer == null)
        {
            lstRawMagXBuffer = new List<double>();
            lstRawMagYBuffer = new List<double>();
            lstRawMagZBuffer = new List<double>();
        }

        bool disturbDetected = false;
        int bufferLength = 200;
        if (sensor.config.mag_sampling_frequency != "standby")
        {
            var x = Convert.ToInt32(sensor.config.mag_sampling_frequency.Replace("Hz", ""));
            bufferLength = 2 * x;
        }

        double isDisturbed = 0;
        magCalibrator magCalibrator = new magCalibrator();
        if (lstMagXBuffer.Count >= bufferLength)
        {
            double[] magXBuffer = lstMagXBuffer.ToArray();
            double[] magYBuffer = lstMagYBuffer.ToArray();
            double[] magZBuffer = lstMagZBuffer.ToArray();

            isDisturbed = magCalibrator.callisMagDisturbanceFcn(magXBuffer, magYBuffer, magZBuffer, 0.3f);
            if (isDisturbed == 1)
            {
                disturbDetected = true;
            }
            else
            {
                disturbDetected = false;
            }
            //Console.WriteLine($"MagDisturbDetect {isDisturbed}");
            //Console.WriteLine("------------------------------clear calibrated buffer");

            lstMagXBuffer = new List<double>();
            lstMagYBuffer = new List<double>();
            lstMagZBuffer = new List<double>();
        }
        else
        {
            lstRawMagXBuffer.Add(streamingPacket.magnx);
            lstRawMagYBuffer.Add(streamingPacket.magny);
            lstRawMagZBuffer.Add(streamingPacket.magnz);

            lstMagXBuffer.Add(calibratedMag[0]);
            lstMagYBuffer.Add(calibratedMag[1]);
            lstMagZBuffer.Add(calibratedMag[2]);
        }

        // DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        if (disturbDetected)
        {
            double[] rawMagXBuffer = lstRawMagXBuffer.ToArray();
            double[] rawMagYBuffer = lstRawMagYBuffer.ToArray();
            double[] rawMagZBuffer = lstRawMagZBuffer.ToArray();
            double[] gainOut = new double[] { 0 }, magXAfterCali = new double[] { 0 }, magYAfterCali = new double[] { 0 }, magZAfterCali = new double[] { 0 }, rmse = new double[] { 0 };

            double[] gainIn = new double[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
            double[] offsetIn = new double[] { 0, 0, 0 };

            // ------> became stuck when executing magCalibrator.callCalibrateMagetometerLiveFcn(...)

            magCalibrator.callCalibrateMagetometerLiveFcn(rawMagXBuffer, rawMagYBuffer, rawMagZBuffer, gainIn, offsetIn, 0.3f,
               ref gainOut, ref sensor.offsetMagCalibrate, ref magXAfterCali, ref magYAfterCali, ref magZAfterCali, ref rmse);

            lstRawMagXBuffer = new List<double>();
            lstRawMagYBuffer = new List<double>();
            lstRawMagZBuffer = new List<double>();
        }
        else
        {
            magCalibrator.callUpdateOffsetFcn((float)streamingPacket.magnx, (float)streamingPacket.magny, (float)streamingPacket.magnz, 0.3f,
                sensor.offsetMagCalibrate[0], sensor.offsetMagCalibrate[1], sensor.offsetMagCalibrate[2], ref sensor.offsetMagCalibrate);
        }
        magDisturbed = disturbDetected;
        return disturbDetected;
    }
```

Comment: The only safe way to kill a thread is for the thread to voluntarily exit. It can't exit if it's waiting for `CalibrateStreamingPacket` to return. You should look for a version of `CalibrateStreamingPacket()` that allows for a timeout or does not block.

Comment: Wow, you start a new thread every not-quite-quarter-second?  You should be addressing that problem first.  That's not a good thing to do in a Windows app.

Comment: Yeah. Why dont use tasks or atleast a threadpool? What is your usage for opening new thread. Perhaps your design is invalid. You can describe us the design and we'll assist

Comment: @ ilansch the sensor streams data at a frequency of 400Hz, initially, each packet should be processed which makes the serialport busy and blocks the UI. so I moved it to background, and assign each package an individual thread. but it does not solve the problem as it takes 200+ms to process a single package.  @ Flydog57 Maybe it is better to call ProcessStreamingData() directly within the while loop in StreamingDisplayMonitor() (run on a background thread). but how to skip / terminate the ProcessStreamingData() when it stucks?

Comment: `CalibrateStreamingPacket` paste this method, there are too many unknowns here to help you other than to say aborting a thread is not an option. There are actually several appraches to solve this problem but none we can suggest without knowing what is going on and why

Comment: Sorry， I did not make it clear, it actually stuck inside the sensor.attitudeHelper.MagDisturbDetect(sensor, streamingPacket, calibrateMag); where it calls a wrapper for a native method. In other words, it became stuck when it calls a native method, and is it possible that I call it to fast? as in the unit test, it works quite well. @TheGeneral

Comment: What native method

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/5222702/34092 .

Comment: @TheGeneral I've pasted the code above, it is a native function within a C++ lib, developed by other guys

Comment: @mjwills, yes, it is. but there is no solution for that...

Comment: `You could create this type of functionality by using a System.Timer (to fire in X seconds and release a locked Mutex) or by using a thread which Sleep's for X seconds - I'd prefer the first method.` Did you try that?

Comment: @mjwills yes, the first version is using the timer, however, it does not work well, it seems it queues the work items which cause an unacceptable lag as time goes by, so in this version I start the StreamingDisplayMonitor() using Task.Factory.StartNew, which seems to work much more reliable.

Comment: Your question is irrelevant to the problem you have. As you mention serialport in comments, what you should do in first place is to read your data packets in async way. That is, pooling of `var streamingPacket = sensor.lst_streaming_data.Last();` should be replaced as a event or a task. Probably your 220ms is not a processing time, but awaits of lock and new thread creation time.

Comment: @ lilo0 to reduce the p/invoke, i did not use the default DataReceived event.. I use the SerialPort.BaseStream.BeginRead() which raises an asynchronous callback to process the received data, that is [01] SerialPort data flow: raw data -> async callback (parse data) -> raise an event (append data to sensor.lst_streaming_data) ;   [02] Data Display Thread: always process the last data in the sensor.lst_streaming_data, this is because the sensor does not stream data in a fixed speed, I want to display the data in a smooth way...

Comment: That's not bad at all, what I would do is to not append data to sensor.lst_streaming_data, but to provide the data as an event to upper level (where processing taking place). I mean every new packet would raise an event. In event handler I would use Interlocked class to help me check does prev processing finishes (lockless!). If some handler still processing packet, skip new one, otherwise set flag and process new packet. What would probably give you the max speed your hardware is capable of for a task.